# Why the "ostream & os" must be there for C++ operator overload?

Tags: c++, overloading

```
// The original code is from link: http://hoeven.blogbus.com/logs/37324287.html
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class test{
public:
     int v;
   /*构造函数*/
     test():v(0){}
     test(const int &a):v(a){}
     test(const test &t1):v(t1.v){}

   /*以下重载小于号 < */
     //比较两个对象的大小
     bool operator<(const test &t1) const{
         return (v < t1.v);
     }
     //比较对象和int的大小
     bool operator<(const int &t1) const{
         return (v < t1);
     }
     //友元函数，比较int和对象的大小
     friend inline bool operator<(const int &a, const test & t1){
         return (a < t1.v);
     }

   /*以下重载赋值号 = */
     //对象间赋值
     test & operator=(const test &t1){
         v = t1.v;
         return *this;
     }
     //int赋值给对象
     test & operator=(const int &t1){
         v = t1;
         return *this;
     }

   /*以下重载加号 + */
     //对象加上 int
     test operator+(const int & a){
         test t1;
         t1.v = v + a;
         return t1;
     }
     //对象加对象
     test operator+(test &t1){
         test t2;
         t2.v = v + t1.v;
         return t2;
     }

   /*以下重载加等号 += */  
     //对象加上对象
     test &operator+=(const test &t1){
         v += t1.v;
         return *this;
     }  
     //对象加上int
     test &operator+=(const int &a){
         v += a;
         return *this;
     }

   /*以下重载双等号 == */  
     //对象==对象
     bool operator==(const test &t1)const{
         return (v == t1.v);
     }  
     //对象==int
     bool operator==(const int &t1)const{
         return (v == t1);
     }  

   /*以下重载 输入>> 输出<< */
     /*友元函数，输出对象*/
     friend inline ostream & operator << (ostream & os, test &t1){
         cout << "class t(" << t1.v << ")" << endl;
         return os;
     }
     /*友元函数，输入对象*/
     friend inline istream & operator >> (istream & is, test &t1){
         cin >> t1.v;
         return is;
     }
};

int main(){
     test t0, t1(3);  // t0 has no initial value, so use default value 0
     test t2(t1);
     cout << t0 << t1 << t2;
     cin >> t1;
     t2 = t1;
     t2 += t1;
     t1 += 10;
     cout << t2;
     if(t1 < t2) cout << "t1 < t2";
     else if(t1 == t2) cout << "t1 = t2";
     else /* t1 > t2*/ cout << "t1 > t2";
     cout <<endl;
     system("echo Tom");
     return 0;
}

/*
 $ ./a.out 
 class t(0)
 class t(3)
 class t(3)
 45
 class t(90)
 t1 < t2
 Tom
 */
```

The complete code is above. But I don't understand why "ostream & os" (see below) must be there in the bracket? If I remove "ostream & os", a lot of errors were given.

```
 friend inline ostream & operator << (ostream & os, test &t1){
     cout << "class t(" << t1.v << ")" << endl;
     return os;
 }
```

Comment: << is a binary operator. You have the ostream on the left side and the thing you want to output on the right side. Since you define this within your class and the first parameter of << is not an instance of your class, this has to be a free function, hence the friend keyword and two parameters.

Comment: I found  that you are quite right. The **friend** key word cannot be removed at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 ways of overloading `operator<<` :

1. **unary** (`this->operator<<(other_object)`),
2. **binary** (`operator<<(ostream& os, other_object`).

**Only one of them is possible** (second), first is impossible because to implement it you have to overload function of ostream class operator<< which cant be done.
When you write statement like `cout << "some text";` **binary operator is invoked**, which gets as arguments: object of class `ostream` and object of another class

Comment: Could you be a little more careful with formatting of your answers? (cleaning up)

Comment: It would have been almost right, but stating that the first option is illegal is just so totally wrong that I am **downvoting this**.

Comment: Ok, could you, please, give me some explanation. I thought that modifying functionality provided in std library is illegal because it can make you code unportable, as written code should follow some standarts to be easily readable and modifiable. So that is actually wrong, is overloading unary operator for ostream legal?

Comment: The point here is that it's not question of _legality_, but question of _possibility_. The class is already written, you can't overload anything in it that's not virtual and you can't add members to it.

Comment: ok thanks, i agree, certainly there is a big difference in terms "legality" and "possibility", thanks for pointing out on my mistake, I shall correct my answer.

Comment: The thing that's "illegal" is adding new definitions into `std` _namespace_ except overloads of existing definitions for custom types and you actually may have to take advantage of that exception here, because often the overload has to be placed in `std` to be properly found by argument-dependent lookup (because pointers don't associate with namespace of pointee type, unfortunately)

Comment: +1. "Possible" is just as good a term as "illegal". Neither is formal ISO terminology. Adding new definitions to `namespace std` formally causes _"Undefined Behavior"_.

Comment: I cannot totally understand what you are discussing. But the main post is what I think the right explaination I expect. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Because the code you paste is wrong.

The << operator should write to its param. i.e. your function should be

```
inline ostream & operator << (ostream &os, test &t1) {
    os << "class t(" << t1.v << ")" << endl;
    return os;
}
```

This gives you the ability to write to any ostream, and not only `cout`. In the previous code, if you wrote `ofile << t1;` (considering `ofile` is a filestream) this would not have write to the file, but still on standard output.

Answer (score 1):

The `ostream & os` is the left hand side of the `operator <<`. i.e. `cout << myObject;`. In this case, `cout` is the `ostream`. However, in your overload, you are ignoring the `os` variable and using `cout` unconditionally. You should replace `cout` with `os` in your `operator <<` overload.

Comment: No, the code is simply broken. It ignores the `ostream` argument and writes to `cout` unconditionally.

Comment: @pmr: The code in question is simply broken, indeed, but as written this answer is consistent.

Comment: @Mark Ingram: This should be called "operator overload" instead of calling it **override**, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Only if you pass the `ostream` variable to the method will the method know where to output. You could alternatively open a file stream and pass it to the method. Then the output would be written to the file instead of to standard output.

Comment: I usually don't comment on how an answer is written, but yours is impossible for me to understand. I think you want to use the word "if", but I'm not sure where. It might help if you broke your answer into multiple sentences.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English,but why don't you just put the word in it?You can edit anyone's answer which is not clear enough or have syntax error　on stackoverflow.

Comment: I wasn't sure where to put the word, since I didn't know what you meant. But now that you've added it, I understand. I made an edit that is waiting for peer review at the time that I'm posting this comment.

Answer (score 1):

The ostream argument gives you further flexibility as to where to direct your output. It also allows chaining so that multiple items can be output in the same statement:

```
test t1;
test t2(5);
test t3(-4);

// Write "0 5 -4\n" to standard output
cout << t1 << " " << t2 << " " << t3 << endl;

// Write "0 5 -4\n" to the file my_file.txt
ofstream ofs("my_file.txt");
ofs << t1 << " " << t2 << " " << t3 << endl;

// Write "0 5 -4\n" to oss, which is then written to standard output
ostringstream oss;
oss << t1 << " " << t2 << " " << t3 << endl;
cout << oss.str() << endl;
```